# Piping output of 'find' to 'xargs wc' gives unreasonable totals

Tags: find, xargs

In a project with thousands of files, I wanted to compare total lines-of-code, to lines-of-code just in PHP (discarding CSS, JavaScript, etc.).

When I run

```
find . -type f | xargs wc -l
```

the total on the last line is *lower* than when I run

```
find -E . -regex '.+\.(php|inc)' -type f | xargs wc -l
```

Considering the second `find` has to be a smaller list of files than (is a strict subset of) the first `find`, how could `wc` report a higher total in the second case?

Answer (score 2):

`xargs` can only pass  [ARG_MAX](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/) bytes of arguments to `wc`.

On my Mac, ARG_MAX is smaller than the full file names and relative paths of the entire project's files, so in the **first** command, `xargs` dumped the results of the `find` to `wc` **in two batches**, which meant that `wc` put out **two totals**, surrounded by thousands of file names.  But ARG_MAX happened to be bigger than the **second** `find` output, so the second, smaller find all showed in **one** `wc` total.

The fix was to use these commands, so I could see all the totals without the (boring) individual file count lines:

```
find . -type f | xargs wc -l | grep total
find -E . -regex '.+\.(php|inc)' -type f | xargs wc -l | grep total
```

Then sum the several "total" rows by hand.

Comment: Or do `find . -type f | xargs cat | wc -l`

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this and `xargs` is not the best. Here are a couple:

1. The simplest, is to `cat` each of the files found by `find` and count the lines. Careful, this only works of your file names have no spaces or strange characters:

   ```
   find . -type f | while read n; do cat $n; done | wc -l
   find -E . -regex '.+\.(php|inc)' -type f | while read n; do cat $n; done | wc -l
   ```

   If your file names are likely to contain weird characters (slashes, spaces etc) use this instead:

   ```
   find . -type f | while IFS= read -r n; do cat $n; done | wc -l
   find -E . -regex '.+\.(php|inc)' -type f | while IFS= read -r n; do cat $n; done | wc -l
   ```
2. A better way is to use find's `-exec` option:

   ```
   find . -name "*.pep" -exec cat {} \; | wc
   find -E . -regex '.+\.(php|inc)' -type f -exec cat {} \; | wc
   ```

Comment: Given that Jeremy’s actual problem was that he had too many filenames to fit on a command line, your first approach is unlikely to work.

Comment: @Scott yup, good point, answer updated.

Comment: Can even `IFS= read –r n` handle filenames containing newlines?   Maybe the ideal solution is a hybrid: `find … –print0 | xargs –0 cat | wc`.

Comment: Darn it @Scott, good point again :). I _thought_ that it could handle newlines because of a comment from a very experienced user on UL.SE which, I now realize, I must have misunderstood. `-print0` also fails on newlines. I removed the reference to newlines to avoid confusion.

Comment: What do you mean, “`-print0` also fails on newlines.”?

Comment: I mean that `find ... -print0 | while IFS= read -r` fails if a filename contains a newline. At least it did a few minutes ago when I tried it.

Comment: Yeah, but that’s not what I suggested.  The `–0` option of `xargs` and the `–print0` predicate of `find` were designed to work hand-in-hand.

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` to sum up the various "total" numbers of the `wc -l` outputs!

(Note: `wc -l` returns the number of newline characters, i. e. final "lines" without a final `\n` character will not be counted - as it is the case with `awk` or `sed`.)

```
export LC_ALL=C
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l | 
    awk '/^ *[[:digit:]]+ total$/{ total+=$1 }END{print total}'


# xargs alternatives using: find ... -exec <wc|awk|sed> ... '{}' +
#man find | less -p '{} \+'

# wc
find . -type f -exec wc -l '{}' + 2>/dev/null | 
   awk '/^ *[[:digit:]]+ total$/{ total+=$1 }END{print total}'

# awk
find . -type f -exec awk 'END {print NR}' '{}' + 2>/dev/null | 
    awk '{ total+=$1 }END{print total}'

# sed
find . -type f -exec sed -n '$=' '{}' + 2>/dev/null | 
    awk '{ total+=$1 }END{print total}'
```